# Duplicating JSON Key

Tags: python, json

Is it possible to duplicate a key using Python functions, without transforming it to text/string?

JSON Input

```
    {
    "lineItems": [
          {
            "sku": "576879",
            "quantity": 2
          }
    ]
}
```

I would like this output, where the first item is duplicated.

```
    {
    "lineItems": [
          {
            "sku": "576879",
            "quantity": 2
          },

          **{
            "sku": "576879",
            "quantity": 2
          }**
    ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: That's not duplicating a key. It's just duplicating a list element.

Comment: Question isn't framed correctly. Keys can't be duplicated (it will overwrite the previous entry if you do). As @Barmar says, you are just duplicating a list element. Kindly rephrase the question like "How to add a duplicate element to JSON in Python?".

Comment: You have a duplicate key in two *different* dictionaries (that are elements of a list).

Comment: Right.  The key is to stop thinking about this in JSON terms.  You have a list containing a dictionary.  You want a second copy of that dictionary in the list.  Easy, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `.append()`:

```py
import json

data = json.loads("""{
    "lineItems": [
          {
            "sku": "576879",
            "quantity": 2
          }
    ]
}""")

data["lineItems"].append(data["lineItems"][0])
print(data["lineItems"])
```

This outputs:

```py
[{'sku': '576879', 'quantity': 2}, {'sku': '576879', 'quantity': 2}]
```

Comment: Hi!, y I already used append but I never thought of copying the existing key using that function! thank you!

Comment: No problem. Have a great evening!